# Exceptions ignored in form_load for x64

Tags: c#, exception, 64-bit, win64

When I throw an exception from form_load in my C# application it doesn't work when the platform is x64. (it acts as expected for x86)

When I step through the code, I get to the line where the exception it thrown, then it immediately jumps to timer_Tick.

When I create a new project and add this line to form_load:
throw new System.Exception("oops!");

For x86 it crashes as expected. For x64 it doesn't crash.

Is there some way to get an application to actually throw from form_load on 64-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind.  Looks like this fell into the black hole of MS known bugs...

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=357311&wa=wsignin1.0